# LayoutInflater in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, layout-inflater

I need help with LayoutInflater.
In my project I'm getting "Avoid passing `null` as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters..." lint warning.
This warning is from Activity when in OnCreate method I have something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
```

It's for inflate a header for example.

I know that when I use LayoutInflater in Fragment or Adapter I have ViewGroup Object and I can pass it instead null but what should I do in this situation when it is in Activity? Should I supress this warning and pass null or create somehow parent object?

**EDIT:**

```
public void addTextField(String message, int textSize) {
    LinearLayout field = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view_field, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) field.findViewById(R.id.taroTextView);
    textView.setText(message);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
    textView.setSingleLine(false);
    mFieldsLayout.addView(field, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

or:

```
public class MyActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_layout, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you not use findViewById in your code instead? But set your layout first using the setContentView before you use findViewById  to get handlers on your code

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you directly call `getLayoutInflater()` in your activity?

As following:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
```

Where the `null` parameter is not a problem. It works fine in my activity.

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the parent that will contain the view.

E.g.:

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.header_container);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, container, false);
container.addView(view);
```

This is only necessary so the view that you're inflating retains it's parent-dependent attributes like the margins. If you pass `null`, those will be set to their default value.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a warning.You sometimes need to pass null. Nothing wrong with it if it is intentional. Many widgets in android framework do it too.

If you want to suppress the warning use this :

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
```

on your statement/ method or class.

For ex:

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
```

or

```
 @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
void yourMethod(){
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
}
```

Just make sure what you are doing here is right. The warning is just for you to check the correctness of your code..

Comment: Could You give me an example of situation when I should pass the parent instead null in Activity?

Comment: Usually for custom layouts.  You can read more here : https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/      What do you do with the view that you inflate ..

Comment: It is only header with name of activity.
I have the project when inflate is use to add header or in dialog to add text (allways with null only in fragments or adapters pass parent) is it a good approach?

Comment: can you share few more lines of your code..  need to know more about how you use the view object...

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView(), false);
```

This way your View has a root (DecorView) to which it is not attached.